# Visual Studio 2010. Error c2143: "синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ; перед ->"

Tags: c++-cli

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Form1->Text="sdfd"; //err c2143
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обращаться нужно к экземпляру класса, а не к самому классу. Form1 - это имя класса, чтобы присвоить значение полю класса, нужно сначала создать экземпляр этого класса (если поле, которому Вы хотите присвоить значение не статическое). В Вашем случае можно сделать так:

```
this->Text = "заголовок окна";
```

Comment: @Данил, но если Form1 - класс, то что же тогда такое System::Windows::Forms::Form ? И как мне обратиться к Text формы из внешней процедуры?

Comment: Form - это тоже класс, он описывает форму, а From1 - это ваш класс-расширение From. Если обратите внимание, то From1 является наследником Form. Чтобы обратится к форме извне, то Вам надо передать туда ссылку на форму, в которой нужно что-то поменять.

Answer (score -1):

Я честно не совсем спец, но, например, в C++ билдер можно задать имя формы графически, в Object Inspector, то есть выбираете форму, а потом идете в Object inspector. Или может там будет пункт Сaption или Text, точно не помню, но со сменой имени меняется Form->Text. Может у вас есть что-то похожее.